# Change variable values with one switch statement

Tags: php, for-loop, switch-statement

Is there any way to go through multiple variables and change their values with switch statement?

let's say i have these variables within a foreach loop:

```
list( $variable1,$variable2,$variable3 ) = explode( '.', $variable );
```

So I split the string to three different variables, each value which was separated with a dot. If it was "1.5.6" then $variable1 = 1, $variable2 = 5 and $variable3 = 6.

Sometimes the $variable might be only "1" or "1.5" etc so $variable2 or 3 might be empty.

By using switch statement I want to change those numbers to something else

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        switch ($variable[$i]) {
        case "1": $variable[$i] = 100; break;
        case "2": $variable[$i] = 200; break;
        case "3": $variable[$i] = 300; break;
        }
    }
```

I used for loop to go through it three times (the number of variables I have split). In the second line I used switch statement and what I'm trying to do there is to go through $variable1, then $variable2 and $variable3.

In order to change their numbers. How can I do it using the actual names "variable1" etc? I don't want to have repetitive code (3 switch statements for each variable). Is it possible to do it with just one within a for loop?

Comment: I think here is your answer: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array which has the keys called 'variable1', etc

```
$array = array();
list( $array['variable1'],$array['variable2'],$array['variable3']) = explode( '.', $variable );
```

Then:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        switch ($array['variable'.$i]) {
        case "1": $array['variable'.$i] = 100; break;
        case "2": $array['variable'.$i] = 200; break;
        case "3": $array['variable'.$i] = 300; break;
        }
    }
```

Then if you really need to have those variables as separate, you can do this:

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
   $kk = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use list() but keep the array it's just another nesting level -> another foreach loop

```
foreach( explode(....) as $v ) {
  switch($v....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (explode('.', $variable) as $v) {
   // do as you please with your $v here.
}
```